# Ipython - What is the difference between c.InteractiveShellApp.pylab and c.TerminalIPythonApp.pylab?

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

For some reason when running the following code in ipython3 / ipython I wasn't able to plot. The window would pop up but would remain grey.

```
$ ipython

import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
# TKAgg

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
# this works!
# Close the window with alt+f4 to get the command line back

plt.ion()
plt.plot(range(10))
# this doesn't work and the plot window freezes (not the terminal)
# Close the frozen window
plt.close()
```

To fix this I instead ran the following:

```
ipython --pylab
```

and now all of the above code works, so I set out to find a way to have this load automatically. So I looked at my default ipython profile config file (`~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`) and I found two blocks of code when searching for `matplotlib`:

```
# Pre-load matplotlib and numpy for interactive use, selecting a particular
# matplotlib backend and loop integration.
# c.InteractiveShellApp.pylab = None
```

and

```
# Pre-load matplotlib and numpy for interactive use, selecting a particular
# matplotlib backend and loop integration.
# c.TerminalIPythonApp.pylab = None
```

So I uncommented the `c.IntractiveShellApp.pylab` and set it to `'auto'` and it all worked but I'm not sure which of the two parameters I should change and what the difference is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree these configuration options are a bit confusing and one might not immediately grasp the difference as it is not explained in comments of that config and descriptions are rather vague. It's pretty surprising they haven't addressed it explicitly. In fact, I've had several lines in `c.TerminalIPythonApp.exec_lines` before reading this question but couldn't remember why I put them there and not in the `InteractiveShellApp` counterpart.

#### Assuming you have IPython 3.x or lower

Comments give us a hint. Under `InteractiveShellApp` section it says:

> A Mixin for applications that start `InteractiveShell` instances.

And after surfing through a chain of links, I've arrived at a doc page for **IPython 1.x** (don't know why they removed that page from future versions) in [online IPython documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/ipython.html):

> Some options, such as extensions and startup code, can be set for any application that starts an `InteractiveShell`. These apps are subclasses of `InteractiveShellApp`. Since subclasses inherit configuration, setting a trait of `c.InteractiveShellApp` will affect all IPython applications, but if you want terminal IPython and the QtConsole to have different values, you can set them via `c.TerminalIPythonApp` and `c.IPKernelApp` respectively.

Finally, consider this comment under `TerminalIPython` section of config file:

> `TerminalIPythonApp` will inherit config from: `BaseIPythonApplication`, `Application`, `InteractiveShellApp`

**Bottom line:** as far as I understand it, `InteractiveShellApp` is for other apps that use IPython API, while `TerminalIPythonApp` is solely for running IPython directly (though not necessarily in interactive mode, `ipython script.py` will also read config settings from it). The former is broader in some sense, as the latter inherits its settings.

To give you a simple example, consider running this under regular Python shell:

```
>>> from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
>>> InteractiveShell()
<IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell object at 0x7fb4a5bee890>
In :
```

So, I guess if you're only planning to use IPython directly (and not as a library) then don't bother with `InteractiveShellApp`.

#### Newer versions of IPython

I don't have any of them installed nearby, so can't say for sure, but after "The Big Split" they might have changed settings a lot. If not, I believe same logic applies.

**PS** Forgot to mention I've written generally about differencies between `InteractiveShellApp` and `TerminalIPythonApp`, but I hope it answers your specific question, too.